# php curl as normal user instead of like a bot

Tags: php, curl

I'm using php curl's to get a page. However, many websites seems to block curl, probably due to the headers / user agent that it is sending. Anyone has a sample curl header that would emulate a normal browser instead?

This is the current header that I use:

```
    $headers[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png, image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, *;q=0.5";
    $headers[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $headers[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[] = "Pragma: ";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
```

and user agent:

```
'Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
```

Comment: Looks like a legit user agent. Maybe they use other mechanisms than the UA header to block bots

Comment: If you want to pretend normal user browsing, do not use curl, but use `headless browser` with javascript support and everything. Websites are unable to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're correctly setting the user_agent?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
```

If so, then I suggest that there might be something else wrong with your query rather than user agent filtering - what issues are you getting, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Download fiddler web proxy and verify what you are sending is the same as a regular browser. When you use fiddler with PHP, be sure to set:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

There may be cookies involved too that you are neglecting.